# Merge multiple dataframes by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

i have a list of data frames

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

for example:

```
>> df1               >> df2                   >> df3
>>     a  b          >>      b  d             >>       e  b
    0  1  2               0  3  4                   0  5  6
    1  9  8               1  7  6                   1  5  4
```

each data frame have a same column name and i want to merge all of them by index. i tried

```
df_merge = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
```

but it doesnt have the expected output.

output

```
>> df_merge
>>    a    b    b    d    e    b
   0  1    6    6    4    5    6
   1  9    4    4    6    5    4
```

expected output:

```
>> df_merge
>>    a    b    b    d    e    b
   0  1    2    3    4    5    6
   1  9    8    7    6    5    4
```

Comment: merging by index is just a concat `pc.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)`

Comment: @Laz, In fact, I don't know where is the problem with your code line? What is the output of your code?

Comment: ah sorry, i see the problem here, i put a simple example but actually i work with a large data and each dataframe have 1 or 2 same columns name but with different values and i still want to merge it by index.

Comment: i already edited my problem

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat` as suggested by @pythonic833:

```
>>> pd.concat(df_list, axis='columns')
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  9  8  7  6  5  4
```

Please refer to the well explained documentation to [**Merge, join, concatenate and compare**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)